# Is custom list an app?

Tags: 2013, app-part

You can add a new app in SharePoint 2013 of type "Custom List". So my question is the "Custom List" an app or not? If it is an app then how come it is created in the host web and not in the app web?

Is there a way to create a new lit in the host web from an app project?

Answer (score 3):

Lists (including "Custom List") are not "real" apps. Your question about "how come it is created in the host web and not in the app web" is spot on. Calling lists apps is a SharePoint "simplification". See this [related post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46828/why-is-a-custom-list-referred-to-as-an-app-in-sharepoint-2013-preview) for details.

As for your other question: an app can create a new list in the host web if it has the proper permissions. See this [blog post](http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.ca/2013/12/sharepoint-2013-apps-access-data-in.html) for details.

Comment: Is there a way to create a new list in the host web by adding the "List" type in Visual Studio? Or do we have to use JS code?

Comment: You should use CSOM, not a full trust solution. If you go the full trust route, your app will need "Full Control". Not a great feature for an app exactly - kinda defeats the purpose. Won't be able to deploy that to O365, for example. See [this post]http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/09/sharepoint-apps-working-with-app-web.html for a full discussion. Specifically, read the section titled "Using the app web vs. the host web".